# How many embrasures?

Tags: graph-theory

We can get a space grid that only contains one small square when we put some 1*2 small rectangles into the grid paper. We name this small square the embrasure. For example, the next left figure contains four embrasures. Then, we can get the maximum _______ embrasures when we put some 1*2 small rectangles into one 4*7 grid paper.

Questions 1: prove the upper limitation.

Questions 2:expand and prove 4*n type.

Questions 3: expand and prove m*n type.

[image]